# Update to 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager

I want to update to 12.04 LTS by following the instructions from [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade), but after pressing Upgrade in the Update Manager, it's downloading the release upgrade tool and nothing happens.

I have checked for updates and installed them just like in the instructions.

What's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing happens"?

Comment: Could do you please click on the "Details" button and see what error showing in command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried another method?

I would **highly** recommend you read this excellent guide here from Ask Ubuntu experts **first**

[Upgrade to 12.04 guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Are you using Ubuntu 11.10 now?

For my pcs that I support and help with I tend to use the terminal to upgrade.

However **this may not suit you if you do not like to use the command line** in Terminal.

If that is ok, then this may work for you.

I open the terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and type the following

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and then follow the prompts. You will need to stay near your pc as you may get asked questions about defaults and any other software you have installed that you have installed.

This will take a long time dependent upon your internet connection and speed of your pc so be patient (*if using a laptop/netbook...make sure it is plugged in!*)

However it has always helped me upgrade easily from each version of Ubuntu.

Usual caveats/warnings apply about backing up any valuable data **BEFORE** you upgrade just in case.